# Class passing itself as a parameter

Tags: java, c++, constructor

So I've been trying to learn C++ for the past couple weeks. I tend to think in java logic when coding in C++.

So say in java I have this code:

```
public class Entity {
    public Entity(){
        Foobar foobar = new Foobar(this);
    }

    public void randomMethod(){
        System.out.println("I am an entity");
    }
}

public class Foobar{
    public Foobar(Entity e){
        e.randomMethod();
    }
}
```

When I create an instance of Foobar, I want to pass the Entity class it was instantiated in, to the Foobar constructor. I'm having a hard time achieving the same code in C++.

*EDIT*
Basically, I want objects, that are instantiated in another class, to know about it's container class.

Comment: Do you have any C++ code already written? so we can work from there?

Comment: That code makes no sense. You'll be recursively calling itself until StackOverflow.

Comment: Ignore the super() call. Sorry about that.

Comment: `Foobar` is used before it is defined. Moreover, the automatic`foobar` is not used.

Comment: @Ben: The `super()` happens automagically if you do not invoke it explicitly.

Comment: Check http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html for an still excellent introduction to C++

Answer (score 1):

This is a C++ version of the Java code in the question. Hope this helps.

```
class Entity {
public:
    Entity();
    void randomMethod();
};

class Foobar : public Entity {
public:
    Foobar(Entity *e);
};

Foobar::Foobar(Entity *e) {
    e->randomMethod();
}

Entity::Entity() {
    Foobar *foobar = new Foobar(this);
}

void Entity::randomMethod() {
    std::cout << "I am an entity";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Java (which does it invisible), in C++ you have to indicate `pointers` yourself.

If you want to reference an existing object you will have to add `&` when calling the method and you'll have to specify the parameter with `*` to indicate it is a pointer.

```
public: Foobar(Entity* e)
{ // logic here
}

public: Entity() {
    Foobar foobar = new Foobar(this);
}
```

Comment: That looks like a munch between Java and C++... And you probably don't want to do `&this` - `this` should be enough.

Comment: `public` must be followed by a colon. `this` is a pointer. `&this` is the address of a pointer. `&this` is ill-formed. Your code is therefore invalid.